# newbie: render different view and layout based on condition loose @object access

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to render a view + layout based on a condition. The following code seems to work but loses access to `@objects` set upfront. I call this code in a `ProfilesController` method Show.

```
@profiles = Profile.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first    

if @profile.nil? == true

  render :view => "show", 
         :layout => "application"
else
  render :template => "profiles/my_profile",
         :layout => "profiles"
end
```

Gives output:

```
undefined method `profiles' for nil:NilClass
```

How could one render based on a condition and still preserve the previous set `@objects` (in this case the access to `@profiles`)

Comment: The error is that you're calling a method `.profiles` on a `nil` object. You should have in the trace the line number. What object is it, and where is it initilazed ?

Comment: Because the @profile object is empty, it seems that rendering under the else part breaks this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting layout in view is not the way to go, its not the rails way and was not advised so even if possible. I changed setting layout in controller action and render the right code in my show partial wich complete solved the issue.